# Hibernate Relationship : Column 'purchaseId' cannot be null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, foreign-keys

I have OneToMany Relationship for Purchase to PurchaseDetails. Purchase Entity have the basic details and PurchaseDetails will have a list of the purchased item. What I want to achieve is when saving the data into Purchase Table (Parent) list of the purchased item also be saved automatically in PurchaseDetail Table (Child).

> 2019-07-19 13:05:53.581  WARN 8868 --- [nio-8060-exec-2]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState:
>   23000
>       2019-07-19 13:05:53.581 ERROR 8868 --- [nio-8060-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'purchaseId' cannot
>   be null

*Purchase.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchase")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Purchase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "purchaseId")
    private BigInteger purchaseId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="accountId", nullable = false)
    private Account account;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="purchase",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetails = new ArrayList<PurchaseDetails>();

    private Date purchaseDate;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String whatsapp;
    private String payStatus;
    private int creditDays;
    private Float loading;
    private BigInteger purchaseAmount;
    private BigInteger receivedAmount;
    private String remarks;
    private Date creation;
    private Date lastedit;
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        creation  = new Date();
        lastedit = new Date();
        isDeleted = false;
    }

}
```

*PurchaseDetails.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchaseDetails")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class PurchaseDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private BigInteger purchaseDetailId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Purchase.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="purchaseId", referencedColumnName = "purchaseId", nullable = false)
//  @MapsId(value = "purchaseId")
    private Purchase purchase;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemId", nullable = false)
    private Item item;

    private Float quantity;
    private Float rate;
    private Float rateGST;
    private Float subTotal;
    private Float subTotalGST;
    private Date creation;
    private Date lastedit;
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        creation  = new Date();
        lastedit = new Date();
        isDeleted = false;
    }

}
```

*PurchaseService.java*

```
@Service
public class PurchaseService {

    @Autowired PurchaseRepository purchaseRepository;

    public boolean newPurchase(Purchase purchase, StringResponseDTO response)
    {
        if(isValidPurchaseData(purchase))
        {
            System.out.println("Service: "+purchase.toString());
            purchase.setPurchaseDetails(purchase.getPurchaseDetails());
            purchaseRepository.save(purchase);
            response.setMessage("Purchase of "+ purchase.getName() + " is added successfuly");
            return true;
    }
        else
        {
            response.setMessage("Please Provide Valid Data");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

*JSON for input from Postman* *(values are only for testing so please ignore subTotal etc )*

```
{
    "purchaseDate":"2019-07-18T08:37:41.000+0000",
    "name":"PersonName",
    "address":"Besides xyz Hotel, NH - 5, India",
    "whatsapp":"1234567899",
    "payStatus":"Paid",
    "creditDays":"0",
    "purchaseAmount":"2600",
    "receivedAmount":"2600",
    "loading":"100",
    "remarks":"Not Any",
    "purchaseDetails":[
        {

            "quantity":"523.6",
            "rate":"67",
            "rateGST":"70",
            "subTotal":"35081",
            "subTotalGST":"36652",
            "item":{
                "itemId":"14"
            }
        },
        {
            "quantity":"222.6",
            "rate":"67",
            "rateGST":"70",
            "subTotal":"35081",
            "subTotalGST":"36652",
            "item":{
                "itemId":"16"
            }
        }],
    "account":{
        "accountId":"4"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` on `purchaseId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a bidirectional relationship with parent and children. If you want to save parent and its children with cascade you need to set the parent on you children also otherwise you will have your error. Please try :

```
for (PurchaseDetail purchaseDetail : purchase.getPurchaseDetails()) {
    purchaseDetail.setPurchase(purchase);
}
purchase.setPurchaseDetails(purchase.getPurchaseDetails());
purchaseRepository.save(purchase);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have on to many relations between Purchase and PurchaseDetails then you should pass Purchase id in PurchaseDetails to make relation, thus :
1. In service layer you should first add Purchase without setting PurchaseDetails 
2. add all PurchaseDetails with same Purchase that added in step 1.

```
@Service
public class PurchaseService {

@Autowired 
PurchaseRepository purchaseRepository;


@Autowired 
PurchaseDetailsRepository purchaseDetailsRepository;


public boolean newPurchase(Purchase purchase, StringResponseDTO response)
{
    if(!isValidPurchaseData(purchase))
    {
        System.out.println("Service: "+purchase.toString());
       //yo should have all PurchaseDetails in a list pay attention this list not null
       List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetails=purchase.getPurchaseDetails();
       //step 1
        purchase=purchaseRepository.save(purchase);
        response.setMessage("Purchase of "+ purchase.getName() + " is added successfuly");
        for(PurchaseDetails adddetail:purchaseDetails){
            //step 2
            adddetail.setPurchase(purchase);
            purchaseDetailsRepository.save(adddetail);
        }
        return true;
}
    else
    {
        response.setMessage("Please Provide Valid Data");
        return false;
    }
}
}
```